# problem getting a value from a JSON array objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, ipad, nsdictionary

Im receiving a JSON array from a UPX server and i cant get to a value

i need the object "name" from "relation_data" but i cant get into "relation_data"

this is how i do it

```
NSLog(@"All of the arrays: %@", json);
    NSDictionary *Allinfo = [json objectForKey:@"response"];//I go into "response"
    NSLog(@"All with response array: %@", Allinfo);
    NSDictionary *datainfo = [Allinfo objectForKey:@"data"];//i go into "data"
    NSLog(@"Data : %@", datainfo);
```

But how do i go into "relation_data" and get the value of "name"?

```
response = (    
data =     (
                        {
                    "business_data_rev" = 12;
                    "contact_set_rev" = 15;
                    currency = EUR;
                    "date_added" = "2011-08-31 12:10:59.338664+02";
                    "date_invoiced" = "2011-08-31 12:10:59.338664+02";
                    "date_modified" = "2011-08-31 12:11:04.45442+02";
                    "date_paid" = "2011-08-31 12:10:59.408335+02";
                    description = "";
                    id = 104;
                    name = "Invoice #104";
                    "person_rev" = 12;
                    realid = 104;
                    "relation_data" =             {
                        id = 12;
                        iscreditor = 0;
                        isdebitor = 1;
                        isprivate = 0;
                        name = "Emre.";
                        "subaccount_id" = 9;
                    };
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[dataInfo valueForKeyPath:@"relation_data.name"];
```

Comment: hmm, if i do this i get all the names(104 records) in 1 variable for example a string, how can i get it 1 by 1?

Comment: try `[[dataInfo objectAtIndex:0] valueForKeyPath:@"relation_data.name"]`

Comment: Thanks solve this problem when i am add the dictionary and then set valueforkeypath.